# Concurrently running gradle/geb tests hanging causing pileup and memory failure "Couldn't get file lock."

Tags: gradle, automated-tests, geb

I apologize in advance for how huge this post is.

I'm running into problems while increasing the number of tasks in my geb test suite, where gradle can't seem to handle multiple concurrent builds at the same time. This has been running successfully for 4 years up until now, where it seems as if the addition of new tasks has hit some sort of threshold in my system. Initially this started looking like connection errors from the selenoid grid, but after upgrading versions, new error messages started appearing that make the problem a little more clear. If anyone can help with this problem I would greatly appreciate it, I've been at it a month and can't seem to get to the bottom of it. Ideally the solution would leave space for further scaling up, as this seems to really be a problem with concurrent tasks.

I will note that reducing the number of tasks scheduled starts to fix this problem, but even at this point I'm not running all of the tasks I'd like to.

Tests run just fine for a few hours, and then the first sign of a problem comes through this message, showing up at the end of a test:

`Couldn't flush user prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock.`

Although my tests are set to timeout after 7 minutes (4 minutes is the expected runtime), the builds start taking longer and longer to complete, starting at 25 minutes and lasting as long as 4 hours (increasing as the container gets closer to the memory limit).

after a few of these messages, these start beginning to appear (sensitive info redacted):

```
[redacted]TestReport: Timeout waiting to lock daemon addresses registry. It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Feb 18 15:10:35 ip-172-30-3-121 [redacted]TestReport: Owner PID: 21092
Feb 18 15:10:35 ip-172-30-3-121 [redacted]TestReport: Our PID: 21030
Feb 18 15:10:35 ip-172-30-3-121 [redacted]TestReport: Owner Operation: 
Feb 18 15:10:35 ip-172-30-3-121 [redacted]TestReport: Our operation: 
Feb 18 15:10:35 ip-172-30-3-121 [redacted]TestReport: Lock file: /root/.gradle/daemon/6.8.2/registry.bin.lock
```

I believe that this has to do with tasks competing for the locked file, the tasks taking increasingly longer to complete, more tasks starting while the previous task is running, and eventually running the docker container out of memory altogether.

Each gradle task takes up to 400mb, but even then there aren't enough tasks scheduled for this to cause a memory failure solely due to too many tasks running at once

I don't think there is much code I can show to help with this question, apart from the scheduling of cron tasks and including what gradle settings I have in place.

My attempt to solve this problem started with upgrading to most recent compatible versions which resulted in 2 weeks of dependency hell, so version numbers reflect this.

**ways I tried to fix this:**

- upgrade dependency versions
- increase jvm heap size, perm size
- split tasks into two docker containers, each running half of the 17 tasks scheduled
- disable gradle build cache (--no-build-cache)
- enable, disable parallel execution (maxParallelForks in build.gradle and org.gradle.parallel in gradle.properties)
- org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true in gradle.properties
- increase maximum number of browser containers in selenoid to 18 (reduce connection pool throttling/timeout waiting for a connection)
- adding timeouts per build
- improve docker cleanups to make sure ecs containers aren't swamped with dead containers (docker system prune on a cron schedule)
- separate build directories per task (named after task name)

**things i think would help**

- a way to designate separate caches per task to avoid fighting for access to locks, can't find a way to implement this
- I was recommended to try running multiple tasks in the same JVM by a java/maven user, but this doesn't seem possible in gradle (each daemon has its own jvm as I understand) and these tasks don't play well sharing build spaces.

**code and infrastructure**

**stack:**

- geb(3.0.1)
- groovy
- gradle (4.3.1 -> 6.8.2)
- docker (running ubuntu)
- java (jre 1.8 -> jre 11/java 8 -> java 11)
- selenium (3.141.59 -> 4.0.0-alpha-7)
- junit (4.12)
- spock (1.1-groovy-2.4)
- selenoid grid (remote)
- docker distributing to ECS containers (16gb)

**general idea of how system works**

- test (type: Test) runs test, generates and stores test report and relevant info
- report (JavaExec task) runs immediately after, sending stored info to appropriate places (firestore and slack)

**cron schedule**

```
*/5 * * * * root cd /tests ; ./gradlew clean test --tests [test1] -Dtest.single=[test1] -DenableVideo=true -Denvironment=http://[hub address]/wd/hub -Dbrowser=chrome   --no-build-cache  --stacktrace --info 2>&1 | logger -t [test1] ; ./gradlew report --no-build-cache --stacktrace --info  2>&1  | logger -t [test1]Report

*/11 * * * * root cd /tests ; ./gradlew clean test --tests [test2] -Dtest.single=[test2] -DenableVideo=true -Denvironment=http://[hub address]/wd/hub -Dbrowser=chrome --no-build-cache  --stacktrace --info  2>&1 | logger -t [test2] ; ./gradlew report  -DclassName=[test2] --no-build-cache --stacktrace --info  2>&1  | logger -t [test2]Report

*/8 * * * * root cd /tests ; ./gradlew clean test --tests [test3] -Dtest.single=[test3] -Denvironment=http://[hub address]/wd/hub -DenableVideo=true -Dbrowser=chrome --no-build-cache  --stacktrace --info  2>&1 | logger -t [test3] ; ./gradlew report -DclassName=[test3]  --no-build-cache --stacktrace --info  2>&1 | logger -t [test3]Report

3 * * * * root cd /tests ; ./gradlew clean test --tests [test4] -Dtest.single=[test4] -DenableVideo=true -Denvironment=http://[redacted]/wd/hub -Dbrowser=chrome --no-build-cache  --stacktrace --info  2>&1 | logger -t [test4] ; ./gradlew report -DclassName=[test4] --no-build-cache --stacktrace --info   2>&1  | logger -t [test4]Report

8 * * * * root cd /tests ; ./gradlew clean test --tests [test5] -Dtest.single=[test5] -DenableVideo=true -Denvironment=http://[redacted]/wd/hub -Dbrowser=chrome --stacktrace --info  2>&1 | logger -t [test5] ; ./gradlew report -DclassName=[test5] --no-build-cache --stacktrace --info   2>&1  | logger -t [test5]Report
```

**gradle infrastructure (from build scan)**

```
Background build scan publication   On  
Build Cache On  
Daemon  On  
Configuration Cache Off 
Configure on demand Off 
Continue on failure Off 
Continuous  Off 
Dry run Off 
File system watching    Off 
Offline Off 
Parallel    Off 
Re-run tasks    Off 
Refresh dependencies    Off 
Task inputs file capturing  Off
```

**ecs/docker infrastructure**

```
Operating system    Linux 4.14.33-51.37.amzn1.x86_64    
CPU cores   1 core  
Max Gradle workers  1 worker    
Java runtime    Ubuntu OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04  
Java VM Ubuntu OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04 (mixed mode, sharing)   
Max JVM memory heap size    1.9 GiB 
Locale  English (United States) 
Default charset US-ASCII    
Username    root
```

here is an example project that my project is based on:

https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle

thanks so much for your time if you're able to help with this.

Comment: Not sure how this is related to Selenoid, so skipping.

Comment: @vania-pooh i will remove this tag. just part of the stack

Comment: Is it possible that your build and/or tests are leaking file handles and the fact that you cannot get hold of these file locks is not really because there is contention over them but because there are no more file handles available?